# How to do integration with respect to $d(x^2)$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have managed to solve it using numerical techniques but I want to learn how to do it by using calculus:

$$\int_0^a \frac{1}{x^2 +x} d(x^2)  $$

Comment: If you let $y = x^{2}$, then the integral should become $\int \limits_{0}^{a} \frac{1}{y + \sqrt{y}}\,dy$.

Comment: The upper limit should be $a^2$.

Comment: @J.G. Are you sure?  It's $d(x^{2})$ which means $x^{2}$ ranges from $0$ to $a$.  Setting $y = x^{2}$ shouldn't change the limits.

Comment: We have $d\left( x^2\right)=2xdx$. I suppose it's possible the OP could intend either meaning. However, when you see $\int_a^b u\frac{dx}{dx}dx$ written as $\int_a^b u dv\left( x\right)$ in a discussion of integration by parts, you'd probably assume $a,\,b$ are $x$ limits.

Answer (score 2):

In general one has
$$
d(f(x))=f'(x)\ dx\tag{*}
$$

Note in particular that $d(x^2)=2x\ dx$ . Can you see how to go on?

---

A related topic to  $(*)$ is called [differential of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function).

Comment: Thanks. I know how to go on from here. However, I dont know why it's equal to 2xdx

Answer (score 2):

For any dependent variable $y$ that depends on a variable $x$, the differential of $y$ is
$$ dy=\frac{dy}{dx}dx,$$
where $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is, of course, the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$. 
Thus, $d(x^2)=2x\,dx$.

Comment: Many thanks! That was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as 
$$
\int_0^a \frac{2x}{x^2 +x} dx  =
\int_0^a \frac{2}{x +1} dx =2\ln(a+1)
$$

Comment: Are you sure the OP didn't mean that $x^2$ should range from $0$ to $a,$ so that the integral would be $\int_0^{\sqrt{a}} \dots \,dx?$ (This assumes that $a\ge 0.)$

Comment: I think that the bounds change to because we go from $x^2=0$ to $x^2=a$.

Comment: That's possible, I just haven't seen that before